# Is there a benefit to starting with MCTS and switching to minimax as the branching factor decreases?

Tags: game-ai, monte-carlo-tree-search, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I've invented a deterministic, perfect-information game with a fairly large branching factor (~150) which tapers out dramatically after the midgame (~30 at worst). I need a strong AI. My understanding from questions like [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/20808/2444) and [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7159/2444) is that it makes more sense to go with MCTS with a large branching factor, but as the game reaches endgame, I'm worried about MCTS missing non-obvious wins due to underestimating their ancestor game states.

I do have some ideas for a heuristic to use with minimax, but since this is a brand new game, it's probably not going to be as good as it would need to be to make minimax worthwhile in general. Instead, I was thinking about using MCTS in the early game, and switching to minimax (with alpha beta pruning) after the branching factor goes below a certain threshold for long enough.

Are there any issues with using an approach like that?